# If a sequence is decreasing and bounded below then it is convegent

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I show the following if a sequence decrease and is bounded below then it is convergent.

This is my "proof" I am not sure if it be correct.
So the sequence $<a_j>$ is decreasing

$a_1\ge a_2 \ge a_3 \ge a_4,....\ge a_n$

We wish to show

lim $a_j=a$

$j\rightarrow \infty$

Where $a$ is the greatest lower bound.

Then let $E=(x|x=a_j)$ E is a set.
Then E is bounded below so

Allow $\epsilon>0$

$\forall x \in E , x \ge a $ when a is lower bound

$\forall \epsilon >0$,$\exists  x_1 \in E$ such that $x_1<a+\epsilon$

Now $x_1$ is in the set $E={a_1,a_2,a_3}$

The let $x_1=a_N$

Now when $j>N$

Since $a_n$ is decreasing $a_j \ge a_n$

and we get the following

$a+\epsilon > a_n \ge   a_j \ge a$

This then means I think

$-\epsilon < a_j-a < \epsilon$

Thus $|a_j-a|<\epsilon$

Comment: Very nice!! It's correct :)

Comment: Ok thanks, I think there be no mistakes